# single-click vs double-click dilemma in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

single-click vs double-click dilemma

I have an event happening for a single-click, and I have a different event happening for double-click.

Single-click: load preview of email message

Double-click: load message view in different window

The issue is that in order for a double-click to occurr, a single-click happens... twice.
The current solution has been to put a timeout on the single-click and cancel it if the double-click is detected.

Question 1: What is the timeout on a double-click event to occur? If I single-click really slowly, it won't take place, for example.

Question 2: Is there a better way to solve this than to use a timeout?

Comment: By going down this route, with user interaction like nothing else on the platform, you run the risk of failing to be accepted into the store (the pause could be interpreted, as not being responsive); and if it was accepted, getting unfavourable reviews. If this is a client request, it may be worth [suggesting they follow the conventions of the platform](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/17397/10930) to be better received by their *customers*

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely rethink your UI. Look at the apps around you, especially in Windows: when double-click is supported, the single-click action is always triggered and is unobtrusive. For instance, when double-clicking on an icon, the first click will select it, and the second one will trigger the action. There's at least two reasons for that:

1. A double-click is a complex maneuver. The user will sometimes fail, triggering the single-click action instead. Therefore, you don't want to do anything that may annoy him.
2. If you don't want the single-click action to be triggered when every time the user double-clicks, you have no other way than putting a timeout. It means that every user trying to use the single-click will have to bear with that timeout, decreasing application responsiveness and hindering user experience.

I can add one more reason, specific to WP7 developpement: as the double-click isn't used in most of the other mobile apps, the gesture isn't discoverable, and most users won't realize they can use it.

Bottom line: consider using another gesture (like a sweep, or a tap-and-hold), or change your UI to make it unnecessary.

Comment: I got specification like that. I have to use single tap and double tap. Can you give me some sample codes to use the time out. I will give you another factor which i am going to use in my project. When single tap a canvas appear in the screen when double tap the grid height should be reduced.

Answer (score 1):

i have found the answer with the help of my friend.

```
private void Button_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        //add the event handler for single tap event
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        //start timer. If the tick happends a single tap happend. If it is a double tap the tick event will be removed.
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }

    //No double tap happend. So execute the tap function.
    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Stop timer
        dispatcherTimer.Tick -= new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        dispatcherTimer.Stop();

        //Rest of the tap function
        Taps.Add("Tap");
    }

    private void Button_DoubleTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        //Stop timer
        dispatcherTimer.Tick -= new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        dispatcherTimer.Stop();

        //Rest of the double tap function
        Taps.Add("Double tap");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use something else. 
tap to open in new windows
hold to preview ?

Answer (score 0):

on wp7, doubleTap is likely never used. Hold would be the right way to go

Comment: I have achieved that using the timer control event. Will microsoft not allow the application which is having double tap and single tap in the same app.If it is kindly let me know

Comment: It's allowed, but unusual and maybe bad for the user-experience. Your simply not used to double-taps on normal controls (except webbrowsers & maps) as a wp7 user.